# How to make Looped rigid body physics?

Tags: rigid-body-simulation, rigidbody

I have A Chain animation. It connects to bone which hac Rigid Bidy constraints.
Animation lasts 100 frames - but i want make it looped.
Cause of physics Bones dont get to their first position,they are just flying randomly.
How to imperceptib[image]ly put them in 100 frame like 1 frame

Comment: I'm not sure you can, but you could bake the animation in order to make the link between the first and last frame